# Are Kendo DataSources able to handle data response sizes that differ from PageSize?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We have noticed that dataSources can drop rows in a few scenarios.  After parsing the data from the server while it's inserting stuff into the dataSource._ranges[] array you can notice that not all of the rows that were received by dataSource:parse() and dataSource:data() are available in the ranges.

If the data response size is less than the pageSize() value then the grid has problems scrolling and paging, and upon scrolling, the dataSource() will continually request (page 1) and (page 2) over an over again.

If the data response size is larger than the pageSize() it might work, but we are unsure.  We have also noticed that if the data response size is 2x the pageSize() then we are more likely to have an issue with data finding it's way in the ranges.

The server is aggregating data from several services and it's hard to predict the number of records that will be returned.

Should kendo support server responses that have more or less data than the page size suggests?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's very hard to understand your problem. Maybe a example or JSFiddle??

Answer (score 0):

If the response size differs from the page size sent in the request, the server is not returning what is being requested of it so I would say all bets are off.  I would expect the client to ignore extra data since it didn't ask for it.  Is your server taking the requested page size into account when it's generating its response?  I can see where it would return less data but should never return more data than requested.